# Show query values with datastax.QueryLogger

Tags: cassandra

I use `com.datastax.driver.core.QueryLogger` in java to display executed queries on Cassandra :

```
        Cluster cluster = new Cluster.Builder().addContactPoints(URL).withPort(PORT)
            .withoutJMXReporting()
            .withoutMetrics()
            .withCredentials("cassandra", "cassandra")
            .build();
    session = cluster.connect();
```

The log I get looks like :

```
2018-10-09 03:24:17 DEBUG NORMAL - [cluster1] [YYYY/127.0.0.1:9042] Query completed normally, took 37 ms: [4 bound values] INSERT INTO client.info (id_client,phone,address,age) VALUES (:id_client,:phone,:address,:age);
```

Is there a way to replace `:id_client, :phone, :address, :age` by the actual values ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If trace is enabled it will display the bound values. ie

```
  <logger name="com.datastax.driver.core.QueryLogger.NORMAL">
    <level value="TRACE"/>
  </logger>
```

Comment: In what file should I write these lines?

Comment: you use log4j or logback? xml or properties file? depends on how you configure your logger.

Comment: I use log4j properties file.

Comment: Then add `com.datastax.driver.core.QueryLogger.NORMAL=TRACE` with i think a `,whateveryourappenderis` like `com.datastax.driver.core.QueryLogger.NORMAL=TRACE, console`

Comment: We have a public repo, sharing example https://github.com/cfpb/hmda-platform/blob/master/hmda/src/main/resources/logback.xml